# How to get entered value after onkeydown?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get new value of an inputbox after entering each character if it's a number. But ajax in example below sends old value and not the newly entered value.

For example, if the value was 1 and I focused the inputbox, deleted the value and pressed 2, Ajax will send "1". But I need it to send "2"

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="quant-input" size="7" name="qty" value="1" onkeydown="change_qty();"/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function change_qty(evt) {
    var charCode = event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 48 || charCode < 57) {
        jQuery.ajax("page.php", {
                type: "POST",
                data:'data='+$('.quant-input').val()
            });
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried changing onkeydown to onkeyup or onkeypress?

Comment: You can't. Onkeydown nothing is entered yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value isn't changed until the keyup event. So you need to use the following instead:

```
onkeyup="change_qty();"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onkeydown
```

will call you function when user just press the button, so, first it will call you function, but then it will insert value in the input. So, you should use

```
onkeyup
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `onBlur="change_qty();"` that will give you the value after leaving focus from the control. Or if you dont dont want to leave the text box and needs the updated value the `onKeyUp` is fine

Answer (score 0):

#### Try these

Use either:

1. Use `onkeyup`.
2. Use the new html5 `input` event, in your case `oninput`:

   ```
   <input oninput="change_qty();" ...>
   ```

Check out <kbd>[this demo](http://jsbin.com/ifekUlA/1/edit)</kbd>

#### A word on binding

You could and also should use binding for your event instead of an attribute:

Instead of:
<input <s>onkeyup="change_qty();"</s>>

Use:

```
$('.quant-input').keyup( change_qty );
```

Or

```
$('.quant-input').on( 'input', change_qty );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onkeydown/onkeypress to make some validation before send ajax (to support  copy-paste and special keys (e.g. Enter) you need additional code)

```js
function change_qty() {
  let key = event.key;
  let oldval = event.target.value;
  let newval = oldval.slice(0,event.target.selectionStart) + key + oldval.slice(event.target.selectionEnd);
  
  console.clear();
  console.log("old value", oldval);
  console.log("new value", newval);

  // validation and ajax code

  // return false;   // will not allow to push key
  return true;       // will allow to push key
 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="quant-input" size="7" name="qty" value="1" onkeydown="change_qty();"/>
```